# Animate layout to fill screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-xml

I'm trying to replicate this animation in Google's Play Newsstand app:

http://i.imgur.com/UuX1PRO.webm

I have a layout that looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ... more layouts ...

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can expand the `LinearLayout` (with ID `post`) to expand to the screen? Note that the height of all posts is 250dp. When the post has expanded to the screen, I want to load the replies made to the post below it (comments section).

How can I create this animation/expand effect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use material design activity transition

See [here](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)

```
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/material-design-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `Activity` transition. The article view is in fact a different `Activity`. See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the following line of code to your Activity.onCreate();

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact solution but I think [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) on developer site is exactly what you are looking for.